# Trouble Understanding Readprocesmemory parameters

Tags: c++, windows, function, memory, readprocessmemory

I am new to c++ and trying to learn the readprocessmemory function. I have some knowledge of c++ but still limited. I can't understand what to put for the parameters of this function. Thank you for reading I have provided a link for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory

Comment: That link explains each parameter. What is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208782/read-memory-of-process-c/48635797